# Why isn't certbot writing the verification file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to install a certificate using certbot on Ubuntu Xenial by using the below command:

```
sudo certbot run -a webroot -i apache -w /var/www/mydomain/public/.well-known/acme-challenge/ -d "example.com"
```

I get a challenge failed error with the following notes:

```
Domain: mydomain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lvJ9RbuDyoPn4NXnxPpjOYpsGHZb6ZYdDoBWW-6JC1k
```

I created the /.well-known/acme-challenge myself thinking this might help, but it didn't.  I tried putting a file into the acme-challenge directory and browsed to it through Chrome and this worked without an issue. Therefore, I know the Apache host is setup correctly.

I'm now at a loss of what to try.

Comment: Do you get HTTP 200 answer from your web server when you browse to http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lvJ9RbuDyoPn4NXnxPpjOYpsGHZb6ZYdDoBWW-6JC1k ?

Comment: No, I get a 204 because the file its trying to get does not exist.  I believe it should create a new file each time I run the command and then authorize against that file. But, it's not creating that file

Comment: You are running certbot as superuser so there can be no permission issue with writing the file? And the directory where the file should be created in does exist?

Comment: Yes.  I have placed a file in there and then browsed to it and downloaded fine.

Comment: Ok so you can create files there manually (withouth certbot) and then you get HTTP 200 and download OK. When you use certbot and try to download the file you get HTTP 204? Not 404?

Comment: Correct and 204